# Python Selenium can't click on next page button

Tags: python, selenium, click

I want to click the next page until no more page, but it does not click.

returns the error:raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

my codes:

Thanks in advance!

```
driver.get('http://www.chinamoney.com.cn/chinese/zjfxzx/?tbnm=%E6%9C%80%E6%96%B0&tc=null&isNewTab=1')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.refresh()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
datefield_st = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "pdbp-date-1")))
datefield_st.click()
select_st = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-year"))))
select_st.select_by_visible_text("2021")
select2 = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-month"))))
select2.select_by_value("1")
day=1
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[@data-handler='selectDay']/a[text()='{}']".format(str(day))))).click()
datefield_ed = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "pdbp-date-2")))
datefield_ed.click()
select_ed = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-year"))))
select_ed.select_by_visible_text("2021")
select2 = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-month"))))
select2.select_by_value("1")
day=1
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[@data-handler='selectDay']/a[text()='{}']".format(str(day))))).click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("查询").click()
while True:
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    links=[link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@title,'同业存单') and not(contains(@title,'申购说明')) and not(contains(@title,'公告'))]")]
    titles = [title.text for title in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@title,'中期票据') and not(contains(@title,'申购说明')) and not(contains(@title,'公告'))]")]
    dates = [date.text for date in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="san-grid-r text-date"]')]
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    for link, title,date in zip(links, titles,dates):
        dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'col1':date,'col2':title,'col3':link},index=[0])
        dataframe.to_csv('Chinamoney.csv',mode='a+',header=False,index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')
        print(link,title,date)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "page-next")]').click()
    except:
        print('No more pages')
```

Answer (score 1):

You passed two class names into selector while it's not allowed for search by class name. Either try

```
(By.CLASS_NAME, 'page-next')
```

or

```
(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.page-btn.page-next')
```

Also your `element` and `icon` select the same element. So you don't need to define `icon`. Simply use `element.click()`

Comment: thanks, but I tried `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="page-next"]').click()`, still wont click

Comment: @Cathy it's not correct. Correct is `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "page-next")]').click()`

Comment: it gives me an error`StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Comment: @Cathy it means that you might do something that refreshes the page and then trying to handle element defined earlier. It's hard to say as I can't see your complete current code

Comment: Please see me edit for the code, not sure what causes that, thanks for your help! I refreshed the page once, as the page is hard to load at the first time

Comment: @Cathy `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "page-next")]').click()` is in try/except - you can't get `StaleElementReferenceException` on that line. On which line exactly you got that exception?

Comment: think in the `links=`line, sometimes works, sometimes return error

Comment: sorry for`titles` line, does the code work form your side

Comment: @Cathy I didn't try. I examine the code statically :) I guess script is trying to scrape new results before DOM completely refreshed. Simplest solution will be to add `time.sleep(2)` as first line of `While` loop. Also remove all the `driver.implicitly_wait(...)` lines - I don't think you need them

Comment: Thanks Jason, it does not return error this time but still won't click...sad face.. just return first page values again and again

Comment: @Cathy do you mean it doesn't click with this line `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "page-next")]').click()`?

Comment: sorry ,yes, it does not click the nest page button somehow

Comment: @Cathy. I'm not sure why. Because I simply tried `While True: time.sleep(2); driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "page-next")]').click()` and I moved all the way to the last page

Comment: it worked for me as well, I delete try, it worked for the second page and stop at the third page again...

Comment: the page is clicking now but won't return the titles contain the 'text', when I put the `click` the same priority with `for loop`, is that correct? sorry for keep bothering you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228203/discussion-between-jason-and-cathy).

Comment: hello again, just one more quick Q: it this correct syntax 'OR': xpath("//a[contains(@title,'中期票据') or (@title,'公司债券') and not(contains(@title,'申购说明')) and not(contains(@title,'公告'))]")]

Comment: @Cathy no. correct is [contains(@title,'中期票据') or contains(@title,'公司债券')...

Comment: Got it ,Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You are using:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "page-next")]').click()
```

Try:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "page-next")]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

If this doesnt work, you can try to obtain the url/link value and store it, and later you can go to the url or do what you want without click in it.

Comment: Thanks! but it still does not work, just return the values in first page again and again, is that I refreshed the website the reason? how should it be fixed?

Comment: What? I dont understand, You say that you have the first url page only? Maybe the driver find more than elements, try to do a find_elements instead of find_element and check the length of the array result, or print the result and see how many elements you have.

Comment: there is only one element found by class name ='page-next',so..

Comment: If the script doesnt enter in the except, extract the href or the attribute where the element has the url, and print it, so you can see where the script is trying to access. If the url is correct, you can access "manually" to it with a get or any "browser" method.